# No instances of constructor Model::Model matches argument list

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when I want to compile my program. This program was initially written in xcode and was running fine. I'm not sure if this has to do with anything but im trying to compile on Visual C++ on Windows. This is the  header and here is where I get the error in cpp file
model.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include "../SOIL2/SOIL2.h"
#include <assimp/Importer.hpp>
#include <assimp/scene.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h>

#include "mesh.h"

using namespace std;

GLint TextureFromFile( const char *path, string directory );

class Model {
public:
    Model( GLchar *path ) {
        this->loadModel( path );
    }

    void Draw( Shader shader ) {
        for ( GLuint i = 0; i < this->meshes.size( ); i++ ) {
            this->meshes[i].Draw( shader );
        }
    }

private:
    vector<Mesh> meshes;
    string directory;
    vector<Texture> textures_loaded;

    void loadModel( string path ) {

        Assimp::Importer importer;
        const aiScene *scene = importer.ReadFile( path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs );

        if( !scene || scene->mFlags == AI_SCENE_FLAGS_INCOMPLETE || !scene->mRootNode ) {
            cout << "ERROR::ASSIMP:: " << importer.GetErrorString( ) << endl;
            return;
        }

        this->directory = path.substr( 0, path.find_last_of( '/' ) );
        this->processNode( scene->mRootNode, scene );
    }

    void processNode( aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene ) {
        for ( GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++ ) {
            aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
            this->meshes.push_back( this->processMesh( mesh, scene ) );
        }

        for ( GLuint i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++ ) {
            this->processNode( node->mChildren[i], scene );
        }
    }

    Mesh processMesh( aiMesh *mesh, const aiScene *scene ) {
        vector<Vertex> vertices;
        vector<GLuint> indices;
        vector<Texture> textures;

        for ( GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++ ) {
            Vertex vertex;
            glm::vec3 vector;

            vector.x = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mVertices[i].z;
            vertex.Position = vector;

            vector.x = mesh->mNormals[i].x;
            vector.y = mesh->mNormals[i].y;
            vector.z = mesh->mNormals[i].z;
            vertex.Normal = vector;

            if( mesh->mTextureCoords[0] ) {
                glm::vec2 vec;
                vec.x = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
                vec.y = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
                vertex.TexCoords = vec;
            } else {
                vertex.TexCoords = glm::vec2( 0.0f, 0.0f );
            }

            vertices.push_back( vertex );
        }

        for ( GLuint i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++ ) {
            aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
            for ( GLuint j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++ ) {
                indices.push_back( face.mIndices[j] );
            }
        }

        if( mesh->mMaterialIndex >= 0 ) {
            aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
            vector<Texture> diffuseMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures( material, aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, "texture_diffuse" );
            textures.insert( textures.end( ), diffuseMaps.begin( ), diffuseMaps.end( ) );
            vector<Texture> specularMaps = this->loadMaterialTextures( material, aiTextureType_SPECULAR, "texture_specular" );
            textures.insert( textures.end( ), specularMaps.begin( ), specularMaps.end( ) );
        }
        return Mesh( vertices, indices, textures );
    }
    vector<Texture> loadMaterialTextures( aiMaterial *mat, aiTextureType type, string typeName ) {
        vector<Texture> textures;
        for ( GLuint i = 0; i < mat->GetTextureCount( type ); i++ ) {
            aiString str;
            mat->GetTexture( type, i, &str );
            GLboolean skip = false;

            for ( GLuint j = 0; j < textures_loaded.size( ); j++ ) {
                if( textures_loaded[j].path == str ) {
                    textures.push_back( textures_loaded[j] );
                    skip = true;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if( !skip ) {
                Texture texture;
                texture.id = TextureFromFile( str.C_Str( ), this->directory );
                texture.type = typeName;
                texture.path = str;
                textures.push_back( texture );

                this->textures_loaded.push_back( texture );
            }
        }

        return textures;
    }
};

GLint TextureFromFile( const char *path, string directory ) {
    string filename = string( path );
    filename = directory + '/' + filename;
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures( 1, &textureID );

    int width, height;

    unsigned char *image = SOIL_load_image( filename.c_str( ), &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB );

    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
    glGenerateMipmap( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );
    SOIL_free_image_data( image );

    return textureID;
}
```

Lines I am getting the errors in my cpp file:

```
Model earthModel("resources/models/earth/Earth.obj");
Model space("resources/models/space/space.obj");
Model sunModel( "resources/models/sun/sun.obj" );
Model mercuryModel( "resources/models/mercury/mercury.obj" );
Model venusModel( "resources/models/venus/venus.obj" );
Model marsModel( "resources/models/mars/mars.obj" );
Model jupiterModel("resources/models/jupiter/jupiter.obj");
Model saturnModel("resources/models/saturn/13906_Saturn_v1_l3.obj");
Model uranusModel("resources/models/uranus/13907_Uranus_v2_l3.obj");
Model neptuneModel("resources/models/neptune/13908_Neptune_v2_l3.obj");
```

Comment: You should paste the full error you get, but the cause is very probably your first `Model` constructor: it takes a `GLchar *` instead of a `const GLchar *`.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Probably it's because you try to pass a `const GLchar *` to a construction which needs a (not const) `char *`.

Comment: for every model:
Error C2664  'Model::Model(Model &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [37]' to 'GLchar *' sloar-system

Comment: also this error 
Error (active) E0289 no instance of constructor "Model::Model" matches the argument list sloar-system

Comment: These clarifications should go in your question, but changing the signature of `Model::Model` to `const GLchar*` should fix these errors.

Comment: The first error message already tells you the important fact: you can't pass a const char* to a char*. Change `Model( GLchar *path )` to `Model(const GLchar* path)`.

Comment: it fixed it but now i get other warnings that wont let my program run

Comment: like those:
Warning C26495 Variable 'aiVectorKey::mTime' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). sloar-system

Comment: You don't need all that code to demonstrate the problem. Read about the [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You have different options.

I propose to modify Model constructor to:

```
Model(string path ) {
    this->loadModel( path );
}
```

So, you will receive a string object that will be passed to the loader.

Another option is to do a casting in the object declaration:

```
Model earthModel((GLChar*)"resources/models/earth/Earth.obj");
```

but I don't like it because could be possible that doesn't match GLchar and char types.

Comment: it fixed it but im getting those warnings :Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C26495 Variable 'aiVectorKey::mTime' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).

Comment: This warning is another problem. Open another question.

Comment: @I: When you ask a new question, please make sure to invest some time to polish it. Make sure that capitalization is correct, fix typos, include the relevant code (including correct code formatting) and provide the exact error message in the question itself.